# How do I have a long custom startup sound play completely?

Tags: boot, sound, startup, music, plymouth

I changed the default startup sound to one that I wanted. However, the song is longer than a few seconds, and only a few seconds of the custom sound play on startup. Is there a way to have the whole thing play?